# bash: White-space in filenames

Tags: bash

I've got a simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp/pics
for pic in *.jpg;
do
  php -f /tmp/pics/covert.php $pic;
done
```

When my pictures have white-space in their names that script won't work. How could I fix that?

How can I fix my script to handle whitespace properly, and also handle other JPEG extensions, such as "JPG", "JPEG", "jpeg"?

Comment: Try speech marks around the `"$pic"`.

Comment: Add quotes around, when having trouble with white space

Comment: No need for the semicolons here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting rules in `bash` and other shells are unlike those in "normal" scripting languages like Ruby and Python and Perl, so this may be confusing at first, but if you put double quotes around `$pic`, bash will treat the contents of the variable properly even if it contains spaces.

That one fix would make your script look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp/pics
for pic in *.jpg;
do
  php -f /tmp/pics/covert.php "$pic";
done
```

I would also remove the semi-colons at the end of each line.  Those are only needed if you're cramming multiple lines together on one line.  They're not needed in bash the way they are in PHP or (to a lesser extent) JavaScript.

As written, this is using the Bourne shell instead of bash.  (For the moment we'll ignore the fact that bash might be used on your system to emulate the Bourne shell.)  Change the "shebang" line at the top if you want to use bash.  Typically it is `#!/bin/bash`.

To handle multiple file extensions, you can just stack them up next to each other with spaces in between, like this

```
for pic in *.jpg *.jpeg *.JPEG *.JPG
```

As Jens points out, you might have odd corner-cases where the file extension is mixed case.  You can handle that with brackets to group characters

```
for pic in *.[jJ][pP][gG] *.[jJ][pP][eE][gG]
```

or you could use glenn's approach of setting your shell options to ignore case (and [non-matching patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob)) and then use a simpler glob pattern

```
shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob
for pic in *.jpg *.jpeg
```

If we take that latter approach, the final script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp/pics
shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob
for pic in *.jpg *.jpeg
do
  php -f /tmp/pics/covert.php "$pic"
done
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Double quotes, btw. Single quotes won't work for parameter substitutions.

Comment: It's similar in PHP, as it doesn't treat them as literals when quoted. But you're right, you were only talking about normal scripting languages. :)

Comment: @Jens: yes, I should clarify that.  In (non-computer-related) American English "quotation marks" means double-quotes, but I think it might be the opposite in British English, and therefore most of the English-speaking world... will fix...

Comment: BTW, your point about restoring the working directory is only an issue if the script is *sourced*, i.e. using `. script` or `source script`.  Directly executing the script (`./script` - which is why you'd add a shebang line), runs the script in a separate process so the script cannot cause side effects in the parent environment, like changing the current directory or environment variables.  A good reason to avoid sourcing scripts.

Comment: @NedDeily: ahh.... you're right.  I've gotten in that habit because I do a lot of sourcing from my .bash_profile and .zshrc, so I can keep things in nice focused files rather than a bazillion lines in one big "ball of mud" file, but I guess it's not normally important.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx: I didn't mean it as a slam on PHP, but I left it out on purpose, because it's not *normally* used for (what I would call) scripting.  I mean, how many sysadmins do you know who manage their systems with PHP?  I realize that some people call *.php files used on web sites "scripts" but I don't use the word that way, and most people I know don't use the word that way.

Answer (score 2):

For short scripts like this I would use

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp/pics
for pic in *.[jJ][pP][gG] *.[jJ][pP][eE][gG]; do
  php -f /tmp/pics/covert.php "$pic"
done
```

This handles even weird camelcasing extensions like `prettygirl.JpeG` :-)

Answer (score 2):

With bash, to do case-insensitive file matching:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob
for pic in *{jpg,jpeg}
do
    php5 -f ./convert.php "$pic"
done
```